# Boolean Operators in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have list of items (separated by comma) that I need to look up in a database. Initially I was looking up each item code individually, but there must be an easier way of doing it.

I was playing around in phpMyAdmin trying to select items with no luck.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE  `code` = ( 20298622
OR 83843296 
OR 46549947 )
```

Returned no results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE  `code` =20298622
OR 83843296 
OR 46549947
```

Returned every item in the database.

I was reading up on the MySQL docs, and it appears that OR (or ||) should do what I'm looking for. Where did I go wrong?

Also, FWIW, `code` is a integer field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `items` 
 WHERE `code`
    IN (20298622,
        83843296, 
        46549947)
```

Comment: This is the most convenient answer since all of the items are already separated by a comma. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason it failed is because the OR statement separates two conditional statements.  Therefore, your first conditional statement would evaluate (`code = 20298622`) but then your next statement is simply a number.  If you want to use the OR statement, you will need to specify the column name again.  Here is what it would look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE  `code` = 20298622
OR `code` = 83843296 
OR `code` = 46549947
```

You could also use more complex statements like IN or you could even do a join to a second table (even a temp table).  Basically, there are a lot of ways to accomplish this.  You will just need to choose which one fits your situation best (speed, ease of use, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct syntax. You should change the statement to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `code` = 20298622
    OR `code` = 83843296 
    OR `code` = 46549947
```

Or as @alex notes on his answer, you can use the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM `items` 
WHERE `code` IN (20298622, 83843296, 46549947)
```